# Pass variable into nested jquery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

```
<script id="mainTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

{{each(i, wrapSpec) data}}

<div id="pkgLineTabs_{{= wrapSpec.wrapSpecId}}" style="font-size:12px" 
     class="reportTable display {{= wrapSpec.wrapSpec2.pkgLineId.hash}}" title="{{= wrapSpec.wrapSpec2.pkgLineId.hash}}" >  

    {{tmpl(wrapSpec.report) "#dayTemplate"}} <!-- need to pass avgOunces variable !-->

</div>  

{{/each}}
```

```
   <script id="dayTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

<!-- need avgOunces variable down here !-->


    <br />
</script>
```

Ok say I have a template like this.  In the nested template call I want to pass a variable that the first template has so it has access to that variable.  How would I go about doing that?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind.  I got it.

```
{{tmpl(reportPerHour, { avgText : avgText }) "#hourTemplate"}}
```

In next template

```
{{= $item.avgText }}
```

Not sure why I need the item variable though.